# Inner array in MySql query result to PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wonder if there is any way to get the results of an `INNER JOIN` into an array for a specific record in `MySql` with `PHP`?

I give an example below:

Table records:
       **`id_record  |   name_record`**
                       `1 |  stocktaking`
                `2 |    statement of account`

Table records_values:
       **`id_rv  |   id_record | date_updated`**
            `001 |   1`                 |  June 1, 2010
    `002 |   1`                 |  March 3, 2011  
    `003 |   2`                 |  March 12, 2010

To perform an `INNER JOIN` between tables `records` and `records_values` for the record with id 1 the result is as follows:

**`id_record | name_record | id_rv  | date_updated`**
                `1 | stocktaking | 001     |  June 1, 2010`
                `1 | stocktaking | 002     |  March 3, 2011`

Finally, I want to know if `MySql` can return those values ​​to `PHP` but grouped within an array, so the result could be as follow:

```
$result = Array
          (
            [id_record] => 1
            [name_record] => stocktaking
            [values] => Array
                   (
                     [0] => Array
                            (
                              [id_rv] => 001
                              [date_updated] => June 1, 2010 
                            )
                     [1] => Array
                            (
                              [id_rv] => 002
                              [date_updated] => March 3, 2011 
                            )
                   )
          )
```

If anyone can tell me a way to do this, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

The result of the query is a single dimensional array only. You need to handle that on the application level. The query you need is,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.id_rv, b.date_uploaded
FROM    records a
        INNER JOIN records_values b
            ON a.id_record = b.id_record
```